# IOS Charts Y- Axis not properly aligned - Charts Cocoa Pod

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, ios-charts

I am currently using IOS charts the link to the library is here: [Link](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

Currently, the charts Left axis labels to not represent what they should. 
The chart is currently zoomed in to allow panning across.

Here is a picture to show the left axis:[image]

The actual dataset however is:

`yValues = [0,2,4,5,3,4,2,4,5,4,4]`

The Left Axis is actually in increments of 0.8.

How do I change this?

Here is what I need:[image]

**Update**

After setting

`leftAxis.granularity = 1`

The plots are where they should be. However, out of [0,1,2,3,4,5]
3 is getting skipped and is not being shown in the left axis. What would cause this?

My Code:

```
`class ReviewDetailVC: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var chartView: LineChartView!

var yValues =  [Double]()
var yLabels =  [String]()
var months = [String]()
var xValues = [String]()
let red = UIColor(hue: 0.9639, saturation: 0.62, brightness: 0.93, alpha: 1.0)
let black = UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.29, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0)
let grey = UIColor(red:0.81, green:0.81, blue:0.81, alpha:1.0)

let avenirDemi =  UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 14)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    chartView.delegate = self
    // Chart Ui Settings

    chartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    chartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = 5
    chartView.leftAxis.labelCount = 7

    chartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
    chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    chartView.legend.enabled = false
    chartView.scaleYEnabled = false
    chartView.scaleXEnabled = true
    chartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
    chartView.highlighter = nil
    chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    chartView.dragEnabled = true
    chartView.scaleXEnabled = false
    chartView.scaleYEnabled = false
    chartView.zoom(scaleX: 4, scaleY: 1, x: 0, y: CGFloat(AxisDependency.left.rawValue))
    chartView.xAxis.labelFont = avenirDemi!
    chartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = grey
    chartView.leftAxis.labelFont = avenirDemi!
    chartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = black
    chartView.xAxis.axisLineWidth = 0
    chartView.leftAxis.axisLineWidth = 0
    chartView.leftAxis.granularity = 1
    chartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
    chartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    chartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
     chartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
    chartView.leftAxis.gridColor = grey
    chartView.leftAxis.gridLineDashLengths = [4]
    chartView.leftAxis.gridLineWidth = 1.5
    chartView.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true
    chartView.noDataText = "This person has not reviewed your business."

    xValues = ["MAR 10"," MAR 15", "APR 7", "APR 8", "APR 15", "APR 30", "MAY 14", "MAY 21","MAY 31", "MAY 31"]
    yLabels = ["0","1","2","3","4","5"]
    yValues = [0,2,4,5,3,4,2,4,5,4,4]

    let Xformatter = CustomLabelsAxisValueFormatter()
    Xformatter.labels = xValues
    let Yformatter = CustomYAxisLabelValueFormatter()
    Yformatter.Ylabels = yLabels

    chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = Xformatter
    chartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = Yformatter



    chartView.animate(yAxisDuration: 1)

    setChart(dataPoints: xValues, values: yValues)


}



func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    chartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i)+0.5, y: 
  values[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
    let chartData = LineChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet])

    chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
    chartDataSet.colors = [red]
    chartDataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = true
    chartDataSet.circleRadius = 16
    chartDataSet.circleColors = [red]
    chartDataSet.circleHoleRadius = 12
    chartDataSet.circleHoleColor = UIColor.white
    chartDataSet.lineWidth = 4


    chartView.data = chartData

}





@IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, 
 completion: nil)
}

}

class CustomLabelsAxisValueFormatter : NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter 
{

var labels: [String] = []

func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        let count = self.labels.count

        guard let axis = axis, count > 0 else {

        return ""
        }

        let factor = axis.axisMaximum / Double(count)

        let index = Int((value / factor).rounded())

        if index >= 0 && index < count {

            return self.labels[index]
        }

    return ""
}


}

class CustomYAxisLabelValueFormatter : NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {


var Ylabels: [String] = []

func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
    let count = self.Ylabels.count

    guard let axis = axis, count > 0 else {

        return ""
    }

    let factor = axis.axisMaximum / Double(count)

    let index = Int((value / factor).rounded())

    if index >= 0 && index < count {

        return self.Ylabels[index]
    }

    return ""
}


}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code this is what I get:

[image]

So I am not able to reproduce your problem, the only thing I changed was to uncomment these three lines, since I don´t have the the code for CustomYAxisLabelValueFormatter. So if you uncomment those lines, it should work.

```
    //let Yformatter = CustomYAxisLabelValueFormatter()
    //Yformatter.Ylabels = yLabels
    //chartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = Yformatter
```

Comment: I just updated the question. I will post my code as well.

Comment: I tried that and I like the effect :) But it does not fix they Left Axis

Comment: Thanks:) I guess I don't even need the formatter than. Always nice to get rid  of a chunk of code!